# Is there a way to change struct channels assigned to a function?

Tags: go

I have functions that pass structs through channels to other functions that differ only by the structs their channels accept.  I would prefer to have one set of functions where I can change the type of struct the channels pass.

For example, in the code below, I would like to be able to switch between channels that pass type A or type B. From what I've read on interfaces, I could select different methods based on the struct type but I would still end up with two or more sets of similar functions.

I have researched `make(chan interface{})` and reflect but I want to specify type for compiling, if possible. Is there another method I am missing?

https://play.golang.org/p/uZ-EO6pdQUX

```
type A struct{
  Name string
  Date time.Time
}
type B struct{
  Name string
  Height string
}
func onealpha (a1 <-chan A, a2 chan<- A){
    for x:=range a1{
        fmt.Printf("%+v",x)
        a2<-x
    }

}
func onebeta (b1 <-chan B, b2 chan<- B){
    for x:=range b1{
        fmt.Printf("%+v",x)
        b2<-x
    }

}
func twoalpha(a2 <-chan A){
    <-a2
}
func twobeta(b2 <-chan B){
    <-b2
}
func main() {
    a1:=make(chan A)
    a2:=make(chan A)
    b1:=make(chan B)
    b2:=make(chan B)

    go onealpha(a1,a2) //receives from a1, does some stuff and sends to a2
    go onebeta(b1,b2)  //receives from b1, does the same stuff and sends to b2

    a1<- A{Name:"Bob"}
    b1<- B{Name:"Marsha"}

    twoalpha(a2)  
    twobeta(b2)  
}
```

Comment: No. Go does not support generics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to extract an interface from your types, example:

```
type I interface {
   GetName() string
}

type A struct{
  Name string
  Date time.Time
}

type B struct{
  Name string
  Height string
}

func (a A) GetName() string { return a.Name }
func (b B) GetName() string { return b.Name }

func onealpha (a1 <-chan I, a2 chan<- I){
    for x:=range a1 {
        fmt.Printf("%+v",x.GetName())
        a2 <- x
    }
}
```

But yes, as it was mentioned above: it's not possible without generics.

There are solutions to this: reflection and code generation.

Comment: I set up interfaces but got stuck with the changing channel types.  Thanks for answering my question.